# Is it possible to bind method arguments to arbitrary positions in Racket?

Tags: racket

This year I'm doing the Advent of Code in Racket, and when I'm parsing the input (saved as a file) I generally map over each line with some method. In some cases, the puzzle input can be mapped directly using something like `string->number`, but in other cases it needs to be split by a non-whitespace string before being further manipulated.

Of course, I can do this using a lambda:

```lisp
; Custom method for handling the input reading
(read-input-lines #:line-parser (lambda (line) (string-split line ","))
```

While this works, it can sometimes be annoying to have multiple nested lambdas to do this and further parsing, and so I'm wondering if there's a way to effectively "bind" ',' to `string-split` so that I don't need to wrap it in a lambda.

In other words, is there a way I can bind an argument value to a specific argument position of a method without using a lambda, e.g. to bind `,` to the second argument position of `string-split`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a helper procedure, so you don't have to define the same `lambda` multiple times:

```
(define (split-by-comma line)
  (string-split line ","))

(read-input-lines #:line-parser split-by-comma)
```

A more generic solution for binding an argument value to a specific argument position of a method without using a `lambda`, would be to use `cut`, found in [SRFI 26](https://docs.racket-lang.org/srfi/srfi-std/srfi-26.html):

```
(require srfi/26)
(read-input-lines #:line-parser (cut string-split <> ","))
```

Comment: `cut` is exactly what I was looking for, thanks Óscar! Also thanks for pointing to SRFI, I didn't know about it and it looks like a valuable resource.